# Can't update Duplicity in Python 3.9.7 (Requested duplicity has inconsistent version: filename has '0.8.21.post7', but metadata has '0.8.21.post0')

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, duplicity

I'm trying to update Duplicity with `pip install -U duplicity`, but it fails with the following output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: duplicity in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.8.20)
Collecting duplicity
  Using cached duplicity-0.8.21.post7.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/01/c8fabb7811feb13d762d976155f3dba912f0dab93f033c655f3180148574/duplicity-0.8.21.post7.tar.gz#sha256=3c526376e61a372c9a5aee8b3a52d4b498d297711d7fb232604ace87c378ba41
(from https://pypi.org/simple/duplicity/) (requires-python:>2.6, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <4):
Requested duplicity from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/01/c8fabb7811feb13d762d976155f3dba912f0dab93f033c655f3180148574/duplicity-0.8.21.post7.tar.gz#sha256=3c526376e61a372c9a5aee8b3a52d4b498d297711d7fb232604ace87c378ba41
has inconsistent version: filename has '0.8.21.post7', but metadata has '0.8.21.post0'
```

I see it uses some cached file, but I failed to find it to try to clear it. Also I see it mismatches some metadata in downloaded file, but it was released a while ago (last Nov) so unlikely anything this critical would be overseen. Still, I'm out of clue how to fix it on my end.

Googling with any parts of this message also didn't bring anything.

I see it was released quite a while ago (last Nov), so I believe it should be something on my side.

If anything, I'm under Ubuntu 21.10 and my Python is 3.9.7.

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. Resolved it using these steps:

- installed the "basic requirements" from `https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/blob/rel.0.8.21/requirements.txt` via pip: `python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir install fasteners future python-gettext "setuptools>=44.1.1" "setuptools-scm>=5.0.2"`
- tried installing duplicity: `python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir install "duplicity==0.8.21.post7"`
- resolved missing system packages as they popped up, then retried

Worked for me after a few rounds :)